Какие есть методы диагностики работы tarantool?
Столкнулся с проблемой что при обновлении Tarantool с версии 1.10 до 2.11. В процессе обновления шарда реплика обновляется успешно, но мастер, отработав несколько запросов, около минуты встает в 100% CPU и не дает зайти в кластер. Из самых примитивных методов диагностики удалось сделать перед смертью fiber.top(), однако там не наблюдалось проблемных файберов, average всех файберов кроме sched (idle) был менее 0.01. Есть ли какие-то разумные методы диагностики кроме тупого переглядывания кодовой базы?
С маленькой нагрузкой кластер работает нормально
